# 2D graphic library for windows form application

Tags: c++, 2d

I need a 2d graphic library for windows form application(Visual studio 2010).I used to work with SDL in console applications.It was really great:simple and powerful.But a friend of mine told me that it won't work in windows form application.Can you please suggest me a good library for 2d drawing in form applications written in C++?Or is there a way to use SDL in windows form applications?
*it would be great if it has these features:
load .bmp and .gif and popular image formats.
Simple to learn.
Draw text and simple 2d shapes.

Thanks.

(Sorry for my bad english)

Answer (score 0):

SDL supports Windows.  You should be able to use SDL by just using a Window's Handle from a control in Windows Forms.  For example, if you initialize SDL to use the a "panel" by passing the `panel->Handle` property as the HWND, it should work fine.

Alternatively, you can use Windows Form's built-in drawing in the [System.Drawing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.aspx) namespace.